# Custom callout getting dismissed in MKMapView when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, calloutview

I have a map view and a custom callout built from scratch. Everything works fine except that the callout disappears whenever user taps on it.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you override `pointInside` in your custom annotation view to account for the callout:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if self.bounds.contains(point) {
        return true    
    } else {
        return self.subviews.contains { $0.frame.contains(point) }
    }
}
```

Then, map view turns out to favour `UIButton` in a callout and won't dismiss if the tap hits an instance of `UIButton`. Make sure that you cover the whole callout view with a button (which may or may not do anything when tapped).

You can add subviews into a `UIButton`, but make sure that they all have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`.